# Is it possible to call html5 in an flash swf?

Tags: html, flash, embed, 2d-games, swfobject

I have a html5 to flash related question. Because flash to html5 is so common,  it is hard to search for. So I want to ask this question directly now:

**Is there a way to use flash to call or embed a html5 game inside the swf?**

background: I have a 2d html5 game, which I want to bring to some gaming portals. There are still many portals, which just add flash games to their sides.
That made me thinking about a walk around to bring my game to this portals as swf in some way. But is it worth thinking about it? I have no clue where to start >.<'

Is it possible?

Comment: Try this https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/html/HTMLLoader.html or fallback option https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html